# Stack or Heap in inderect heap allocation

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

is funcVar on stack or heap in scenario 1?

I'm asking because I suspect that it is, and hence this may be a good way to do things to minimize memory leaks.  that is to say, it may be better to give things auto allocation locations and then place code at higher levels on the heap which would put things at lower levels on heap indirectly as in scenario 1.

In scenario 2, delete may never be called. By using code as in scenario 1, I hope to minimize (not eliminate) issues as in scenario 2.

**Scenario 1**

```
class Test{
    int memVar = 1;

    void func(){
        int funcVar = 2;
        SomeClass::someFuncThatCouldCrash();
    }
};

Test* t = new Test();
```

**Scenario 2**

```
class Test{
    int memVar = 1;

    void func(){
        int* funcVar = new int(2);
        SomeClass::someFuncThatCouldCrash();
        delete funcVar;   //May not free due to crash in line above;
    }
};

Test t;  //or Test* t = new Test()
```

Comment: It's not clear what this code is meant to do. `funcVar` is never used aside from having a value assigned to it, and `someFuncThatCouldCrash` doesn't modify it.

Comment: Thanks, iirc and RyanP, I cleaned up code to be more clear.  Xirema, this code does not do useful things, I kept it lean to keep it clean and focused just on allocation and memory clean up.

Comment: _is funcVar on stack or heap in scenario 1?_ Someone will say that it is neither stack nor heap, for the standard doesn't mention any of them.

Comment: In crash do you mean the application crashing? In that case the operating system will reclaim all memory you didn't free, so this is not an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In scenario 1 `funcVar` (assuming it is `int funcVar = 2`) is on the stack when `func()` is called and in scenario 2 it is on the heap. You are correct, if `someFuncThatCouldCrash` threw an exception it would never be deleted.

Also, in scenario 2 you delete `funcVar` and then return it.. that's no good. Also in that case your returning a pointer when the return type is a regular int.

In C++11 you don't ever want to handle raw new and delete. Basically, most everything should be a variable on the stack. If you need heap allocations, use something like a vector which is a local variable on the stack that manages heap allocations internally. That way, when the vector leaves scope it cleans up itself without ever having to call delete. This is known as RAII (resource allocation is initialization) if you want to look it up further.

In the case that you do need a pointer to an object (such as holding a polymorphic object via base-class pointer, or creating instances of large classes in general) then you would want a `std::unique_ptr` to essentially create that local variable which is responsible for calling `delete` on the object you created. Under rarer circumstances you also may need a `std::shared_ptr` but you can look up what that does and why you'd need it if you want.

Comment: Hmmm... so in Scenario 1, memVar would be on the heap but funcVar would be on the stack, is this correct???  I assumed that because memVar is pushed to heap indirectly in scenario 1, what would be the "call stack" for that function would also be pushed to the heap... but I guess not.

Comment: @code In scenario 1 the instance of test `t` is on the heap, therefore `memvar` (again, it needs a type) would be a part of that object on the heap. When you call `func()` it becomes a function on the call stack, and all of it's local variables (including `funcVar`) are a part of that stack frame.

Comment: I see.  So would you say that there is really no cleaver way of escaping memory leaks like in Scenario 2 without using std::unique_ptr or std::shared_ptr?

Comment: @code You could write your own memory management class if you want, but that's a lot of work when either unique_ptr or shared_ptr exist solely for that purpose already. Basically, anywhere memory is allocated on the heap (via new, malloc, etc) you want the corresponding deallocation (delete, free) to be run from the destructor of an object that is on the stack somewhere. That way, even if an error is thrown and not all code is executed, when that object gets destructed the resources it controlled aren't leaked.

Answer (score 0):

In the first scenario, it is allocated on the stack. In the second scenario, it is allocated on the heap, and you are correct that it leaks if an exception is thrown from `SomeClass::someFuncThatCouldCrash` that is caught further up the stack.

If you want to keep the memory safety but use dynamic allocations, you should be using `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` depending on the use case.

Answer (score 0):

Local variables in automatic storage are on "the stack".

Class member variables are on the "stack" or "heap" depending on if the instance of the class is on the "stack" or "heap".

Global data, including static locals and static class member variables, are on neither the "stack" nor the "heap".

thread local data is in neither the "stack" or "heap" (but it may be implemented on the heap).

So scenario 1 has `funcVar` as a local variable, hence on the "stack".  The instance of the class `Test` is on the heap.

In scenario 2, `funcVar` remains on the "stack", but *what it points to* is something on the "heap".  It is indeed not exception safe; if an exception is thrown it can leak.  A crash is going to clean up any "leftover" simple memory resources on nearly any operating system.  There are sometimes some resources in some situations you can aquire that are not recycled on process exit, but they aren't what `malloc` or `new` return.

Use of `std::unique_ptr` and `std::make_unique` mitigates almost all such leaks.  In modern C++, avoiding raw pointer allocation and memory resources that are not explicitly owned in the type system is generally considered a good idea.